# Ajuste fino no Ranking pra um sistema de jogo

Tags: mysql, query, select

Estou com um problema muito doido que ja queimou minha capacidade lógica.

Há um tempo atras postei uma pergunta quase igual a essa mas e me auxiliaram bastante (agradeço muito) mas minha necessidade mudou e agora estou com outra tabela e minha consulta mudou bastante, pedi ajuda a um professor e chegamos a isso:

```
select * from (
(SELECT distinct nome_jogador,pontos,datahora, 1 as ordem
from jogador j inner join pontuacao_fx p 
on j.id_jogador = p.id_jogador  WHERE pontos > (SELECT pontos FROM pontuacao_fx WHERE id_jogador=7 )
ORDER BY datahora desc, pontos desc)

union

(select distinct nome_jogador, pontos,datahora, 2 as ordem
from jogador j inner join pontuacao_fx p 
on j.id_jogador = p.id_jogador where pontos = (SELECT pontos FROM pontuacao_fx WHERE id_jogador=7 )
)

union

(SELECT distinct nome_jogador,pontos,datahora, 3 as ordem
from jogador j inner join pontuacao_fx p 
on j.id_jogador = p.id_jogador WHERE pontos < (SELECT pontos FROM pontuacao_fx WHERE id_jogador=7 )
ORDER BY datahora desc, pontos desc);

) order by ordem asc,datahora desc, pontos desc
```

Estou de MYSQL gratuito com workbench e o erro é esse:

> ERROR CODE:1248: EVERY DERIVED TABLE MUST HAVE ITS OWN ALIAS.

Tenho que fazer esse ranking agora com a classificação por pontuação e caso haja empate, por data e hora em que a pontuação foi inserida (ja fiz no `BD` os comandos pra guardar data e hora automaticamente no insert e update dos pontos) sendo a pontuação mais recente dada como maior.

Mais uma vez peço encarecidamente socorro.

Comment: Somente com isso fica difícil entender o que você quer. Mostre como está suas tabelas e explique melhor o que você quer.  Esse `id_jogador=7` é a base para todos os cálculos? Será passado o valor ou será sempre 7? Aproveitando, faça um [tour] e veja melhor como funciona o site.

Comment: Olá Luís. Se ainda precisar de ajuda, por favor edite sua pergunta acrescentando mais detalhes. Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

O erro já diz tudo. Você precisa definir um alias para sua tabelas derivadas. Olha o exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT SUM(`quant`), MONTH(`date`) AS month, `id` 
from (
  ... inner select 
) 
group by id, month;
```

O Correto seria:

```
SELECT SUM(`quant`), MONTH(`date`) AS month, `id` 
from (
  ... inner select 
) as t -- this is the change
group by id, month;
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25341000/4007642)